# How are the the structure decks in "Yu-Gi-Oh! 5D's World Championship 2010: Reverse of Arcadia" unlocked?

Tags: yu-gi-oh-world-championship-2010

In *Yu-Gi-Oh! 5D's World Championship 2010: Reverse of Arcadia*, I've unlocked a couple randomly (as far as I can tell), but I'd like to be able to buy them all. Does anyone know a way to unlock them all? And possibly a way to buy multiples of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every 10 wins, a new one will be available for purchase. No, you can't buy duplicates.

Additionally, you can only unlock structure decks that you have won with.

EDIT: Found it! I didn't notice this before since I didn't move on in the game until I won using every single structure deck thinking that there's supposed to be some hidden reward.

Comment: I'm not sure that is correct. I've dueled more than 10 people since I started getting structure decks and I haven't unlocked one since the first three.

Comment: Have you won all 10 of them? I'm pretty sure they don't have to be consecutive wins though, just 10 wins even if it was against the same person.

Comment: Yes I've definitely won more than 10 of them

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I wish some of these guides I've been reading what have just spelled that out better... Thanks